# Execute only if string contains a ','?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to execute a bunch of code only if the string I'm searching contains a comma.

Here's an example set of rows that I would need to parse (name is a column header for this tab-delimited file and the column (annoyingly) contains the name, degree, and area of practice:

```
name                             
Sam da Man J.D.,CEP
Green Eggs Jr. Ed.M.,CEP
Argle Bargle Sr. MA
Cersei Lannister M.A. Ph.D.
```

My issue is that some of the rows contain a comma, which is followed by an acronym which represents an "area of practice" for the professional and some do not.

My code relies on the principle that each line contains a comma, and I will now have to modify the code in order to account for lines where there is no comma.

```
def parse_ieca_gc(s):  

    ########################## HANDLE NAME ELEMENT ###############################

    degrees = ['M.A.T.','Ph.D.','MA','J.D.','Ed.M.', 'M.A.', 'M.B.A.', 'Ed.S.', 'M.Div.', 'M.Ed.', 'RN', 'B.S.Ed.', 'M.D.']
    degrees_list = []

    # separate area of practice from name and degree and bind this to var 'area'
    split_area_nmdeg = s['name'].split(',')
    area = split_area_nmdeg.pop() # when there is no area of practice and hence no comma, this pops out the name + deg and leaves an empty list, that's why 'print split_area_nmdeg' returns nothing and 'area' returns the name and deg when there's no comma
    print 'split area nmdeg'
    print area
    print split_area_nmdeg

    # Split the name and deg by spaces. If there's a deg, it will match with one of elements and will be stored deg list. The deg is removed name_deg list and all that's left is the name.
    split_name_deg = re.split('\s',split_area_nmdeg[0])
    for word in split_name_deg:
        for deg in degrees:
            if deg == word:
                degrees_list.append(split_name_deg.pop())
                name = ' '.join(split_name_deg)

    # area of practice
    category = area
```

re.search() and re.match() both do not work, it appears, because they return instances and not a boolean, so what should I use to tell if there's a comma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way in python to see if a string contains a character is to use `in`. For example:

```
if ',' in s['name']:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if re.match(...) is not None :
```

instead of looking for boolean use that. Match returns a MatchObject instance on success, and None on failure.

Comment: No problemo! Be sure to check python documentation its very good although the RE section is a bit wordy :P

Answer (score 1):

You are already searching for a comma. Just use the results of that search:

```
split_area_nmdeg = s['name'].split(',')
if len(split_area_nmdeg) > 2:
    print "Your old code goes here"
else:
    print "Your new code goes here"
```